# Swift Completion Handler from Class Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have this classe in swift

```
  @objc class NetworkManager: NSObject{
   var dataRepositories: [repositories]!
   static let shared = NetworkManager()

func request_repositories(_ completionHanlder: @escaping ()-> Void){
    Alamofire.request("https://api.github.com").responseJSON { (response) in
        let data = response.data
        // print(response)

        do{
            let r = try JSONDecoder().decode(repositories.self, from: data!)
            self.dataRepositories = [r]
             completionHanlder()

        }catch let error{
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

}
```

and I can't call request_repositories in objective c Class

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NetworkManager *man;


@end
@interface NetworkManager ()
-(void)request_repositories;
//-(repositories*)retornar;
@end


@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   self.man = [NetworkManager alloc];
   [self.man request_repositories];
   [[NetworkManager new] request_repositories];




  }


@end
```

I have doubt I can call a completion handler within the objective c class c, if yes how can I do this, I'm new to programming ios and I have doubts, I'm doing it this way because I do not know how to work with json in objective c, if someone has a suggestion better thank you

Comment: Why can't you call `request_repositories`? Do you get some kind of error, is the code simply not working?

Comment: the code does not work